# How make a reference to a particular key/values dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, reference

I'm wondering if it is possible to make a reference to a particular key of a dict.

For instance, if I create a dict :

```
D={0:[1,2,3],1:['a','b','c']}
```

and a reference to the 0 list

```
ref_D_0=D[0]
```

I can print the value of the 0 key of D dict

```
print(ref_D_0)
# [1, 2, 3]
```

but if I modify the D dict:

```
D[0]=[3,2,1]
print(D) # {0: [3, 2, 1], 1: ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

then ref_D_0 still give me the previous value of D[0]

```
print(ref_D_0) 
#[1, 2, 3]
```

What I would expect is that ref_D_0 refers to D[0] instead making a copy of it.
Did I misunderstand something about referencing in python?

Comment: Mandatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `ref_D_0=D[0]`, you make the variable `ref_D_0` refer to the same object currently held at `D[0]`.

When you reassign either of those, you are not modifying that object, you are only modifying the variable to refer to a different object.

```
D[0]=[3,2,1]
```

Now `D[0]` and `ref_D_0` do not refer to the same object, because you just set `D[0]` to refer to something else.

If you modify the object instead of just reassiging the variable, e.g.

```
D[0].append(0)
```

Then you will be able to see the change reflected in `ref_D_0`, because then the two variables will still refer to the same object.

Comment: "you are only modifying the variable" => "you are modifying which object the variable refers to"

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers How about now?

Comment: that's better ;-)

Answer (score 2):

When you write `ref_D_0=D[0]` the value `ref_D_0` uses the dict to look up its current value (the list  `[1,2,3]`). After that, *it has no connection* to the dict, just to the value of its `0` key. If you change *that* list *(eg `D[0][1] = 5`), the value of `ref_D_0` will change too. However, you don't. Instead, you assign *a new value*. What you do is essentially equivalent to

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a # they point to the same list
a = [3,2,1] # they don't anymore
```

So, to sum up, you didn't misundestand. `ref_D_0` refers to the object currently in `D[0]`, it is not a copy. However, if that object is *replaced* (not *changed*), your `ref_D_0` still refers to the original object.

The only way to do what you want would be to have a pointer to `D[0]`, but there is no such thing in python.

Answer (score 2):

`ref_D_0` refers to a particular object.

`D[0]` refers to the same object.

`D[0] = [3, 2, 1]` creates a new object and makes `D[0]` refer to it, replacing the original object.

Of course this doesn't affect `ref_D_0`. Why should it?

If you want to *modify* the list instead of replacing it in the dictionary, you can `append`, `insert`, or even assign to a slice, e.g. `D[0][:] = [3, 2, 1]`. This will affect `ref_D_0` as they both still refer to the same object.